# Maclaurin series for $x e^{x^2-1}$

Tags: analysis, taylor-expansion, euler-maclaurin

i have done everything to that step$$xe^{x^2-1}=f(x)=\frac 1 e \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{x^{2n+1}}{n!},$$ but I need $f^{(101)}(0)$ so I know that I need to find $2n+1=101$ which is $n=50$. But I don't know what to do next. That answer is correct? $$f^{(101)}(0)=\frac 1 e \cdot \frac 1 {50!}$$

Comment: what do you mean by $f101(0)$? the 101-derivative of $f$ in zero?

Comment: Yea i have to find that

Comment: You need $f(x)$ rather than $f(n)$ and $\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty$ rather than $\sum\limits_{i=0}^\infty. \qquad$

Comment: My edit was to change the typo f(n) to f(x).

Comment: @NombreFalso123. It is fairly common in this context to use  $f^{(k)}$ (with round brackets around $k\;$) for  the $k$th derivative of $f. $

Comment: My second edit was more typos, and "I" for "i" but more importantly to define $f(x)$..... I hadn't known that I could use \frac 1 e instead of \frac {1}{e}.   And I tried to italicize "define" in this comment by putting dollars around it but I get $define$...... :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Where you wrote $\displaystyle f(n)=\frac 1 e \sum_{i=0}^\infty \frac{x^{2n+1}}{n!}$ you need instead $\displaystyle f(x)=\frac 1 e \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{x^{2n+1}}{n!}$ (with $f(x),$ not $f(n),$ and with $\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty,$ rather than $\sum\limits_{i=0}^\infty).$

The term of degree $101$ is
$$
f^{(101)}(0) \frac{x^{101}} {101!} \quad = \quad \frac 1 e \cdot \frac{x^{101}}{50!},
$$
so consequently
$$
f^{(101)} (0) \quad = \quad \frac 1 e \cdot \frac{101!}{50!} \quad = \quad \frac{101\cdot100\cdot99\cdot98\cdot97\cdots  51} e.
$$

Answer (score 4):

To seek $f^{(101)}(0)$ you need this term from the Maclaurin series: $\frac{f^{(101)}(0)}{101!}x^{101}$.

As you have found, your series has a term with the appropriate power of $x$: $\frac{1}{e}\frac{x^{101}}{50!}$.

So set these things equal and solve for $f^{(101)}(0)$.

---

(Also, as @MichaelHardy points out in the comments, a few things are not right with your presentation of the question.)